# Cannot invoke 'responseArray' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire, with ObjectMapper, things were so smooth before upgrading to Swift 2.0, now,

For the following signature:

```
public func responseArray<T: Mappable>(completionHandler: ([T]?, ErrorType?) -> Void) -> Self
```

I'm calling

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
            .responseArray { (response: [MyObject]?, error: NSError?) in

        }
```

and getting the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'responseArray' with an argument list of type
>   (([MyObject]?, NSError?) -> ())

Any help will be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
    .responseArray { (response: [MyObject]?, error) in
        //your process
    }
```